# How to drop a row using idmax in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns date,type,subtype,total. I grouped it with date,type and subtype and found the count of total. Then I tried looping the dataframe to find max and min value from grouped dataframe and pass it into dictionary. Then it should delete the min and max row from dataframe. Again it should find min and max and store it into dictionary.
I'm not able to delete the min and max rows. Can someone help me to achieve this
Attached the code.

```
Combo_Dict = {}

for index, value in df_grouped_data.iterrows():
    
      max_Var = df_grouped_data[[('total', 'count')]].idxmax()
      max_Var = list(max_Var)[0][2]
      min_Var = df_grouped_data[[('total', 'count')]].idxmin()
      min_Var = list(min_Var)[0][2]
      Combo_Dict[max_Var] = min_Var
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input data of your dataframe and expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal   Attached the output from the group by

2011-01 BEVERAGE ENG BREAKFAST TEA 4 True
GRENADINE 11 True
ICED LEMON OR STR CAMOMILE 2 False
M & M SHAKE 2 False
RED BULL 2+1 14 True
RED BULL 3+2 3 False
STRAWBERRY LITE SHAKE 1 False
THE AFTER EIGHT SHAKE 11 True

i want the output should be

RED BULL 2+1 STRAWBERRY LITE SHAKE
GRENADINE   ICED LEMON OR STR CAMOMILE 
ENG BREAKFAST TEA M & M SHAKE

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you want to achieve but I guess you want to have a total count for each groupby and delete the one with the most and least amount of counts.

Without knowing what your data looks like, this is how I would try to solve the problem:

```py
df['group_count'] = df.groupby(['date', 'type']['subtype'].transform('count')
filtered_df = (df
    .loc[
        (df.group_count > df.group_count.min())    # all but the minimum
        & (df.group_count < df.group_count.max())  # all but the maximum
    ]
    .drop(['group_count', axis=1)
)
```

I hope this helps a bit, otherwise, feel free to give some more details on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Yes, I want to have total count for each group by and store the max and min values in a dictionary then delete that max and min values. I want to do this untill all the rows get deleted from dataframe